# Opening Excel file with PowerPoint VBA, Inconsistent Results

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint macro that should open an Excel file.

```
Public Sub SortList()

Dim MyFile as String
Dim xlApp as Object
Dim xlWorkBook as Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    MyFile = SelectedItems(1)
End With

xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open MyFile
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
```

This code was previously working with no errors. However, I have started receiving the error message

> "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed."

The error occurs when trying to run the "Set" line of code.

The issue is that I can see that the code is successfully opening the Excel file!
Things I have tried (in about every possible combination):

-Changing the code to this (I thought maybe the program was trying to open the file twice):

```
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
```

-Adding ReadOnly:= True to both or either .Open command, at one point this gave me an "Automation error- unspecified error" message which I have never seen before...

-Changing the Set line to this (and variations thereof):

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open MyFile
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks(Dir(MyFile))
```

-Ensuring Excel is completely closed prior to running the code

The frustrating aspect is that this code worked perfectly last week, so I'm also at a loss as to why it would suddenly stop working. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont understand why you are opening it twice... you should be able to remove this and it  should work just fine: `xlApp.Workbooks.Open MyFile` - assuming `SelectedItems(1)` is a valid filename including the full path.

Comment: Is the folder in which the Excel file is stored synced via OneDrive?  That has been known to sometimes cause issues, historically

Comment: The folder is synced via OneDrive, although I did still experience the error after copying the Excel file over to the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

`Workbooks.Open` can cause issues if you call it on an already open workbook.

So, don't open twice. Remove the following line:

```vb
xlApp.Workbooks.Open MyFile
```

Comment: I had tried the code with that line commented out and it was still experiencing the same error. For better or for worse the code in its current form has without explanation or change started working again, but if it works just as well without that additional line I'll leave it out. Based on some additional digging I've done, I think there are some features of the network I'm on that may have been intermittently preventing the file from doing what it should have done, and they are unfortunately beyond my control. Thanks for responding!